# Bidimensional array and pointer problems

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-address, datareader

I'm working on a project using *ublox m8t*, I'm reading several packages and one of those is *sfrbx*.

```
struct buffer {
    // The buffer's length are overestimated
    u_int8_t rawbuf[1024];  //THE LENGTH IS UNKNOW, PROB AROUND 300BYTES
    u_int8_t clkbuf[NAVCLOCK_LENGTH+10];
    u_int8_t navposbuf[NAVPOSLLH_LENGTH+10];
    u_int8_t navpvtbuf[NAVPVT_LENGTH + 10];
    u_int8_t sfrb[16][1024];
};
```

`sfrb` is the bidimensional array we're talking about.

After reading the package I pass it in a function for processing it.

---

**Function Delcaration:**

```
void decode_rxmsfrb(u_int8_t rawbuf[][],struct rxmsfrbx *ptrsubframe[], int n);
```

**Function.c:**

```
void decode_rxmsfrb(u_int8_t sfrbx[][], struct rxmsfrbx *ptrsubframe[], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned char sv = = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][1]);

    for(j=0; j<n;j++){
        ptrsubframe[sv]->gnssid = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][0]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->svid = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][1]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->reserverd1 = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][2]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->freqid = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][3]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->N = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][4]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->reserverd2 = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][5]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->version = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][6]);
        ptrsubframe[sv]->reserverd3 = *((unsigned char*)&sfrbx[j][7]);

        /* Now we have to read the subframe and then parse it */
        for(i=0; i<ptrsubframe[sv]->N;i++){
            ptrsubframe[sv]->dword[i] = *((unsigned int*)&sfrbx[j][8+4*i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Function call in main:**

```
decode_rxmsfrb(bufinformation0.sfrb, &subframe,k);
```

---

The problem is that the compiler doesn't like `sfrbx[j][8+4*i]);` I guess because it's trying to map 2 different zones of the memory (`J` and `8+4*i`).

When I use this kind of addressing with a normal array, like this:

```
nav->gSpeed = *((signed int*)&rawbuf[64]);
```

It works.

Why do I get this problem?

Edit Solution: void decode_rxmsfrb(u_int8_t rawbuf[16][1024],struct rxmsfrbx *ptrsubframe[], int n);

Comment: Your function doesn't know the dimensions of the matrices you are passing in, so how can it know how to address the elements of the matrix?

Comment: I did function(u_int8_t buffer[],...) everywhere and it works with the monodimensional array like in the example at the end.

Do u mean when i call the function in the main with bufinformation.sfrb, or in the declaration, i have to pass the dimension?
Because i want to point 1byte of memory in the address at buffer[0][1], buffer[0][2],...,buffer[j][i]

Comment: With only one dimension, getting the address is as simple as adding an offset from the base, which is calculated by multiplying the size of the data type by the index.  With two dimensions, you now have to know how many columns there are per row in your calculations.

Comment: Ok, that's not a problem. I thought there wasn't a problem with 1 or more dimensions but yeah he can't know which is the array with the data and which is the "base".
Thanks :)